What's the translation of "stand-up meeting" in French?
A stand-up meeting meeting is a:

meeting in which attendees typically participate while standing. The discomfort of standing for long periods is intended to keep the meetings short

What's the translation of "stand-up meeting" in French?
Google translate and Linguee suggest "réunions debout", however I never heard that term.

Peut-être que ça ne se fait pas en France?

Si, ça se fait, c’est un grand classique de diverses démarches « agiles » dans le développement informatique notamment.

@StephenKitt J'en conclus que je ne suis invité qu'à des réunions associées à des démarches « rigides » alors ;-) Bon, il m'arrive quand même d'être debout et de me déplacer durant des réunions puisque aujourd'hui, la majorité de celles auxquelles je participe se font en distanciel.

J'ai été dans plusieurs entreprises françaises qui faisaient un "stand-up meeting" et on appelait ça un "stand up meeting".
Dans le milieu professionnel c'est assez courant de voir reprendre des termes "techniques" tels quels sans les traduire. Dans ces entreprises là, tu serais mieux compris à utiliser le terme anglais plutôt qu'à parler de "réunions debout".

100% d'accord avec cette réponse. Si on tient vraiment à traduire en Français, on pourrait utiliser le mot "entrevue" pour évoquer la brièveté de la réunion.

Oui, c'est comme briefing et debriefer.

Jemox - dans quelle industrie/type d'entreprise?

@Frank : Projets informatiques, par exemple.

@Graffito Oui, ça marche pour la tech, mais je ne sais pas si c'est très répandu en dehors. Je me demande si la réponse de Jemox n'est pas un peu trop large.

Je serais vraiment curieux de savoir si ça marche en dehors de l'info. A mon avis non. Les mots anglais sont plus répandus dans l'info que dans eg l'agro-alimentaire ou le BTP.

Il n'est peut-être pas possible d'utiliser le terme anglais "stand-up meeting" en dehors d'entreprises de la tech. Mais je n'ai pas l'impression que le concept de ce type de réunion existe beaucoup en dehors de la tech non plus.

Notez que ce n’est pas parce qu’un mot anglais est employé tel quel en français que son sens est le même : j’ai souvent entendu parler de stand-up meetings… assis! La raison d’être d’une réunion debout pour être courte a été lost in translation…

@Jemox Dans ce cas, la réponse devrait peut-être le préciser. Sinon, on a l'impression que le mot est courant dans toutes les entreprises, ce dont je doute fortement.

Je n'ai jamais entendu “stand-up meeting”, juste “stand-up”.

@Frank Dans les entreprises qui en font, on dit "stand-up meeting" (ou "stand-up"), et dans celles qui n'en font pas, on n'a pas de mot car on en parle pas. Je ne vois pas bien en quoi la réponse serait trop large.

@TeleportingGoat Trop large, parce qu'elle peut donner l'impression que ça se fait en dehors de la tech. C'est à mon avis spécifique aux boîtes d'info, ça ne se pratique sous ce nom-là que dans les boîtes d'info.

Je n'ai jamais participé, vu ou même entendu parler jusque là de « réunion debout » en France, y compris dans les sociétés américaines implantées ici.
Les seules « réunions debout » que je connaisse sont celles qui se font de manière informelle autour d'un distributeur de boissons. Elles n'ont pas de nom particulier. Au mieux, ce sera un « On se retrouve autour de la machine à café ».
Réunion debout se trouve néanmoins décrit dans des sites web français et dans des ouvrages sur les réunions et pourra donc être utilisé, probablement en fournissant une explication en note de bas de page à la première utilisation.

La réunion debout
C'est la quintessence même de la réunion rapide pour programmer l'action. Personne n'aime rester debout immobile plus de 10 minutes. Ici, c'est cet élément « reptilo-limbique » qui est exploité à plein pour favoriser la brièveté et l'efficacité des échanges. Cette habitude trouve probablement sa source à l'armée, quand le général réunit ses officiers pour les passer en revue, avant de lancer ses troupes à l'assaut. Cet usage est aussi courant, semble-t-il, sur les chantiers, et les lieux de production comme les usines. Il se justifie chaque fois que la bonne coordination de tous est, au jour le jour, indispensable à la réussite d'un projet précis.
Louis Timbal-Duclaux, Les réunions: avant, pendant, après, 1995.

Le terme stand-up tout seul existe mais ne s'applique qu'à des spectacles où un humoriste est debout, seul sur scène.

Voici un autre article sur ce type de réunions: https://www.codexa.fr/animer-une-reunion/stand-up-meeting-reunion-debout-idee-de-taille/ Je comprends que les gens se sentent envahis par l'impérialisme culturel gringo dans le monde des affaires. Cela dit, réunion debout ne choque pas en tant que traduction puisque cela rend bien l'idée. +1

@Lambie C'est pas une question d'impérialisme, mais de savoir si c'est une pratique courante ou pas, et dans quel industrie. Dans la tech, ok. En dehors, je ne sais pas.

@Frank  J'ai parlé de sentiments. On les a ou on ne les a pas.

Je ne connaissais pas stand-up meeting, ni réunion debout d'ailleurs. Résultat de ma recherche de quelques quarts d'heure : réunion debout est vraiment très employé en Afrique subsaharienne, beaucoup moins en France où stand-up meeting  est employé souvent avec une explication et associé avec une référence à un style de management.

Les stand-up meetings sont utilisés en informatique, dans la méthode Scrum de développement agile, très répandue. Je les ai pratiqués pendant 6 ans. C'est une réunion quotidienne entre développeurs pour résumer les travaux de la veille, identifier les difficultés, et se partager les tâches de la journée. Comme cela doit durer 10 à 15 minutes et qu'il y a 4 à 8 développeurs, rester debout encourage la concision. De plus, souvent on déplace des posts-its sur un tableau mural. Dans l'ensemble, c'est très agréable. Et on appelle ça "stand-up", ou "daily meeting"...

@Jean-ArmandMoroni Intéressant. Le très répandue m'interroge encore. J'ai cherché toute la semaine des boites qui pratiquent la chose mais je n'en ai pas encore trouvé. En revanche, les post-its sur un tableau, ça oui, j'en vois beaucoup. Ce sont des développeurs dans des domaines particuliers ?

@jlliagre Ce sont des projets en France, à EDF ou Enedis par exemple. De l'informatique de gestion très standard. Les développeurs des SSII que nous employons connaissent en général déjà Scrum, ce qui laisse penser que c'est répandu ailleurs aussi. Je doute en revanche que ce soit aussi répandu en informatique scientifique ou embarquée (dans lesquelles j'ai aussi pratiqué).

@Jean-ArmandMoroni Ok, merci.
